# Geodesics on two-dimensional sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Be a two-dimensional sphere. If we have a curve C and geodesics curves in the sphere that are normal to C. Is true that these all geodesics meet in one point?

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I would say that this is true only when your curve $C$ is planar. The common point corresponds to a vector orthogonal to all the tangent vectors of $C$.

Comment: So, when $C$ is a circle, in other words? That feels right to me, too.

Comment: when C is a circle, C is planar.